# Querying BigQuery tables in a given date range

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery i have tables in the following format: `daily_records_yyyy_mm_dd` . I need to run a query over multiple tables in a given date range. The TABLE_DATE_RANGE function expects table names to be in the format [prefix][day], where [day] is in the format YYYYMMDD. 
Can i still use TABLE_DATE_RANGE in my case or is there some other way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you cannot use TABLE_DATE_RANGE here as it requires specific format

In your case (for `BigQuery Legacy SQL`) - you should use [TABLE_QUERY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#table-query) where you can use any expressions to choose tables

Also - for `BigQuery Standard SQL` - you can use [_TABLE_SUFFIX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) pseudo column to also work with any table name format

Examples:

Legacy SQL

```
SELECT *  
FROM (
  TABLE_QUERY(YourDataset, 'LEFT(table_id, 14) = "daily_records_" 
                            AND LENGTH(table_id) = length("daily_records_") + 10
                            AND DATE(REPLACE(RIGHT(table_id, 10), "_", "-")) 
                            BETWEEN DATE("2015-11-01") AND DATE("2016-01-30")')
)
```

Standard SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM `YourDataset.daily_records_*` 
WHERE REPLACE(_TABLE_SUFFIX, "_", "-")
      BETWEEN "2015-11-03" AND "2016-01-05"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per your suggestion i looked into both TABLE_QUERY and TABLE_SUFFIX but I'm having trouble formulating the query using either of those for a given date range.For example suppose i want to select all records for tables between daily_records_2015_11_01 and daily_records_2016_01_30, what query should i use ? Thanks.

Comment: added example for you

Comment: Thanks so much ! :). The Legacy SQL query with TABLE_QUERY works, but the Standard SQL involving TABLE_SUFFIX gives the following error: Error: No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: DATE(TIMESTAMP, [STRING]); DATE(INT64, INT64, INT64) at [3:7] .

Comment: to make it fast  - try for now: `WHERE REPLACE(_TABLE_SUFFIX, "_", "-") BETWEEN "2015-11-03" AND "2016-01-05"` . but ideally you should check date functions for Standard sql and adjust code. If you still will have issue with dates related function  - let us know

Comment: This works now.Sorry i didn't get what you were trying to say about using date functions. Is it fine to write the standard sql query this way without using the date function or are there any drawbacks ?. Thanks

Comment: it is ok in your particular case - as ordering dates and strings in your case is the same. but in more generic cases when you manipulate and compare dates you better cast string to date